# HTML project doesn't opens properly in chrome on Samsung Tab Active2 Tablet

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I've transferred a whole HTML project (Folder with CSS, HTML, JAVASCRIPT files, ETC.) to my Samsung Tab Active2 Tablet (to files folder) and when I open the HTML file in Chrome or any other browser it seems that the CSS and javascript doesn't work at all. The whole styling of the product has gone and the images tags and buttons doesn't work. it only show HTML text.

I'll be glad to have your help here guys :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're better off installing a local webserver on your device, there's tons of simple http webserver apps.
Working with a filesystem serving html and assets sucks and will cause you more headache than results.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the your folder that you transferred to your tablet is un zipped, and try it on `chrome` web browser.